# Replacing a cell value with another in the last row of a sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to replace a value in the first column in the last row of a spreadsheet with another value. For example I have a workbook with two sheets called Input and Data. I have a value on the input sheet in cell A1. I would like this value to replace the value located in column A in the last row with a value in the Data sheet. I know how to locate last row of the worksheet using the code below, but I am not sure how to input a value located in this last row. What can I add to this in order to retrieve the value I have in the sheet Input in cell A1, and replace the value in column A in the last row of the Data sheet

```
Dim LR1 As Long
'Selects the last row with values
With Sheets("Data")
    LR1 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Comment: `.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row = Sheets("Input").Range("A1")`

Comment: with  @ScottCraner's solution, you would replace the `LR1` line with his code. You can also just add `.Range("A" & LR1) = Sheets("Input").Range("A1")` below the `LR1` line.

Comment: I just realized when I copied and pasted I forgot to delete the `.Row`. `.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp) = Sheets("Input").Range("A1")`

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate the help. Both of these solutions work well for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full solution below:

```
Dim LR1 As Long
    With Sheets("Data")
        LR1 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A" & LR1) = Sheets("Input").Range("A1")
    End With
```